# Unable toget record from Database to View Using AJAX in Laravel 11

Tags: laravel

## **Description:**

I'm attempting to fetch data from my Laravel 11 application using AJAX, but I'm encountering issues with displaying the fetched data on the console.

**Code Snippet View:**

```xml
<script src="{{ url('js/jquery.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    call()
    
    function call() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/testimonial",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response.record) 
        }
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```

**Code Snippet Controller:**

```php
function testimonial()
{
    $rec = tbltestimonial::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    // $rec= tbltestimonial::all();
    return response()->json(['record'=>$rec]);
}
```

**Code Snippet Route:**

```php
Route::get('/testimonial', [admincontroller::class, 'testimonial'])->name('testimonial');
```

**Issue:**

I expect the `console.log(response.record)` statement to display the fetched data in the console. However, when I execute the code, nothing appears in the console. but it directly dispaly the code on screen in json format

**Additional Information:**

- The `/testimonial` route in my Laravel application is correctly set up to return JSON data on screen.
- When I manually access the `/testimonial` route in my browser, I can see the JSON data.

Any insights into why the data isn't being logged to the console would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try with `php artisan view:clear` (or `php artisan optimize:clear`). Check in the docs for the details what are those commands for.

Comment: Can do all the things but not working Does there is any update/syntax change for that in laravel 11

Comment: can my approach is correct ??

Comment: You are missing important troubleshooting information here. What does "it directly display the code on screen" mean? What is your browser's network inspector telling you? Or the error console? Does it show a request being made?

Comment: Try `console.log(response)`, maybe it's nested in a `data` key